# Spring @Bean instantiation depending on @Value annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot and having trouble initializing one of my beans correctly. The definition goes like this :

```
@Configuration
public class BeanConfiguration  {
    @Value("${foo.config}")
    private String fooConfig;

    @Bean
    public Foo getFoo(){
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.setConfig(fooConfig);
        return foo;
    }
}
```

Then, when using the foo bean autowired the foo.getConfig() is null. At the time the bean Foo is created, Spring has not yet populated the fooConfig value from the application.properties file.

What would be the proper way to instantiate the bean? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@Configuration` itself is not a bean. Example you shown seems to be simple.

My suggestion is add Component scan to package wherever the Foo class exists using the `@ComponentScan` annotation over BeanConfiguration class. Autowire fooConfig within Foo class itself.

Comment: Component was not needed in the example and was confusing, my bad. Adding ComponentScan did the trick. Thanks!